# How to search the BLE/ Bluetooth device when app is background or inactive state in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I know lost of questions are there related to this, but didn't get the proper solution so can you please help me.

I'm stuck here from last 2 days

1. Can we search the Bluetooth/BLE devices when app is in background.
2. Can we search the Bluetooth/BLE devices when app is inactive mode

Comment: yes, check answer from here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652592

Comment: @goat_herd Thanks for your comment. I can search the devices when the app is in background mode. Now just want to know how can we do this when the app is inactive mode.