# Bluetooth / BLE devices searching when app is inactive in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, core-bluetooth

I already ask a similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63394414/how-to-search-the-ble-bluetooth-device-when-app-is-background-or-inactive-state) but didn't get the Ans and I solve the one question from the previous post.

Now I'm facing this issue so anyone help me out to do this.

Can I just search the Bluetooth / BLE devices when my app is an inactive state and I never before connected to that device?

Comment: Inactive or Background??

Comment: @PrakashShaiva  When the app is inactive.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you are using and explain what you have tried/what happens

Comment: there is some discussion going on here https://github.com/opentrace-community/opentrace-ios/issues/4 check if it is helpful for you.

Comment: @Paulw11 you can check my code [Here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656003)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you are using and explain what you have tried/what happens